# Limiting fractional digits with NSNumberFormatter SpellOutStyle

Tags: swift, number-formatting, nsnumberformatter

I'm trying to create meaningful accessibility labels for my iOS app and hitting what I think is a strange problem/limitation of NSNumberFormatter.

```
import UIKit

let decimal = 171.8926
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
print(formatter.stringFromNumber(decimal)!)
// "171.89"

formatter.numberStyle = .SpellOutStyle
print(formatter.stringFromNumber(decimal)!)
// "one hundred seventy-one point eight nine two six\n"
```

It seems that `.SpellOutStyle` does not honour `maximumFractionDigits` for some reason.

Am I missing something or do I have to truncate them myself like an animal?

```
let truncDecimal = Double(Int(decimal * 100)) / 100.0
print(formatter.stringFromNumber(truncDecimal)!)
// "one hundred seventy-one point eight nine\n"
```

It seems crazy I can use the formatter to strip digits for numerics but not for words.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift NSNumberFormatter numberStyle SpellOutStyle prints the number out in full for the current locale.

To do what you want I recommend creating a double extension:

```
extension Double {
    func roundToPlaces(places: Int) -> Double {
        let divisor = pow(10.0, Double(places))
        return round(self * divisor) / divisor
    }
}
```

And then you can call your code like this:

```
let decimal = 171.8976
let formatter = NSNumberFormatter()
formatter.numberStyle = .DecimalStyle
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 2
print(formatter.stringFromNumber(decimal)!)
// "171.89"

formatter.numberStyle = .SpellOutStyle
print(formatter.stringFromNumber(decimal.roundToPlaces(2))!)
// "one hundred seventy-one point nine"
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew the concept of multiply-and-divide to round it, but hadn't thought of putting it in an extension, which is an elegant solution.